# Comparator as a current detector with shunt resistor v2

Tags: current-measurement, voltage-measurement, comparator, orcad, over-current

I have a comparator with a shunt resistor that measures the voltage and when the voltage of 12 V from the source exceeds the Vref (1 V in my case) it switches to "high" output. I would like to design this schematic to also switch to "high" when the voltage exceeds -12 V. Is it also possible to design with an AC current source instead of an AC voltage source and decrease the value of the shunt resistor to 10mΩ that will work with the simulation?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Tomcat55 - You wrote an "answer" but it was asking a *question*, so it was misusing the site & has been deleted, sorry. || Since you asked the question, please **don't** use the box labeled "Your Answer" below unless you are writing the *full & final* answer to your own question (i.e. unless you don't need further help & you solved the problem yourself using a different solution than any other answer). Instead, to add more info, please edit the question. (Make sure not to invalidate existing answers or extend the question.) Or *comment* to respond to an answer (e.g. to ask for clarification).

Comment: FYI If you want to add image links in a comment, you can use [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/310525) technique. Note that the draft answer (or question) *must not be submitted*. The draft answer (or question) is used only to upload the image & is then discarded. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply add a second op-amp with the appropriate negative 1V reference voltage and 'or' the two outputs with a couple diodes and resistor to -V or GND.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fAhY0a.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The output will go to about +10V when the input exceeds +1V or is less than -1V.

You can apply suitable resistor dividers. The values you've chosen in your schematic are extremely low for practical purposes and will draw excessive current. Something more like 1kΩ/11kΩ would be more suitable.

Comment: And what are the 2 diodes and resistor exactly doing in the output?

Comment: The pair of diodes and resistor 'or' the two outputs as described in the first sentence above. If either one of the op-amp outputs is high, the output is high. If both are near -12 then the output is at 0V.

Answer (score 0):

To detect two different voltages, you need two comparators.  You also will need two separate reference voltages, one for each comparison.

The LM324 is an opamp, not a comparator.  If you want to combine the two output signals into a single one that reflects both comparisons, you will need OR-ing diodes or transistors.

Here is a link to how a basic window comparator works:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Window_detector